# show out of stock products in pages in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I sell records…
I would like to make visible some "out of stock" products in some of my WordPress pages (the artist's page). The products should stay hidden in the shop but visible in the release catalogue.

All products are set to "catalog and search", yet they don't show in the shop (what's the difference between catalog & shop?) neither in the search results…

I've tried some `[products tag="this-artist" orderby="date" order="DESC" visibility="visible"]` with several options, but nothing worked…

any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your active child theme functions.php file

```
add_shortcode( 'out_of_stock_products', 'render_out_of_stock_products_shortcode' );

function render_out_of_stock_products_shortcode() {

   $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key' => '_stock',
            'value' => 1,
            'compare' => '<'
         )
      ),
      'fields' => 'ids',
   );

   $product_ids = get_posts( $args ); 
   $product_ids = implode( ",", $product_ids );

   return do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids']");

}
```

Then use the shortcode `[out_of_stock_products]` to any pages, posts, templates or widgets.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it show every single available product…